# Use a method in another class and navigation

Tags: react-native, methods, navigation

I am coding an application that is neccessary to login users and I am experiencing a problem.
I have in my App component a getUser () method that I would like to call from other components. I also have a Login () method that allows you to navigate to another page. Only the problem is that I can not export the StackNavigator and App at the same time. Would there be a way to export the StackNavigator and my function? Or an other solution that would solve my problem?

```
class App extends Component<{}> {

    //get the user and return it
    _getUser() {
        return user
    }

    //authentify the user and go to is profil
    _userLogin() {
        navigate('Profil');
    }

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View>
            <Button
            title="Login"
            onPress={() => this.Login() }
            />
            </View>
        );
    };
}

export default StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: App },
  Profil: { screen: secondScreen },
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution, I ll store the user in an asynchron storage.